# Chamando uma função na Views em codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

Tenho essa função no `models`:

```
function sumContasReceber() {
    $this->db->select('lancamentos.*');
    $this->db->from('lancamentos');
    $somaCR = "SELECT SUM(valor) as SOMACR FROM 
            lancamentos where baixado = 0 AND tipo = 'receita'";
    $resultado = mysql_query($somaCR);      
    return $this->db->get()->result();    
}
```

E essa função no `Controllers`:

```
public function index() {
    if((!$this->session->userdata('session_id')) || (!$this->session->userdata('logado'))){
        redirect('mapos/login');
    }

    $this->data['somaReceber'] = $this->mapos_model->sumContasReceber();
    $this->data['somaPagar'] = $this->mapos_model->sumContasPagar();
    $this->data['contasPagar'] = $this->mapos_model->getContasPagar();
    $this->data['contasReceber'] = $this->mapos_model->getContasReceber();
    $this->data['ordens'] = $this->mapos_model->getOsAbertas();
    $this->data['ordensAG'] = $this->mapos_model->getOsAgendamento();
    $this->data['ordensAP'] = $this->mapos_model->getOsAguardandoPecas();
    $this->data['ordensA'] = $this->mapos_model->getOsAndamento();
    $this->data['produtos'] = $this->mapos_model->getProdutosMinimo();
    $this->data['os'] = $this->mapos_model->getOsEstatisticas();
    $this->data['estatisticas_financeiro'] = $this->mapos_model->getEstatisticasFinanceiro();
    $this->data['menuPainel'] = 'Painel';
    $this->data['view'] = 'mapos/painel';
    $this->load->view('tema/topo',  $this->data);      
}
```

E na `Views` isso:

```
echo 'Valor Total R$: '**aqui ta minha dificuldade**;
```

O que eu coloco na View pra chamar o resultado da função da `Model`?

Já tentei: `$somaPagar->valor`, `$somaPagar->$resultado` e mais um monte de variantes más sempre da erro.

Comment: Coloque o código completo do Controller, e outra coisa o método do Model me parece inconsistente.

Comment: Virgilio... a função completa do Controller não cabe aqui nos comentários... vou fazer na resposta.

Comment: Faz na pergunta.

Comment: pronto... já to quase careca....

Comment: qual o erro que aparece?

Comment: não estou conseguindo fazer com que apareça na view o resultado da conta que estou fazendo na models..

Comment: Eu entendi o que deseja, em suas tentativas você disse que apareciam sempre erros, apareceu algum erro do php ?

Comment: sim MagicHat... em todas as tentativas, aparecia que não reconhecia a função ou a variável não existia...
E verifiquei N vezes e não tinha erro na digitação... então não sei mais o q faço.

Comment: Coloque o erro do php,

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: resultado

Filename: mapos/painel.php

Line Number: 104
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: mapos/painel.php

Line Number: 104
Valor Total R$:

Comment: Na tentativa anterior, coloquei isso na view:
echo 'Valor Total R$: '.$somaPagar->$resultado;

Comment: coloca ou aponta o trecho referente a linha 104.

Comment: na linha 104 está isso: echo 'Valor Total R$: '.$somaPagar->$resultado;

Answer (score 3):

***Mude o código como está abaixo:***

```
function sumContasReceber() {

    $somaCR = "SELECT SUM(valor) as SOMACR FROM lancamentos
                          where baixado = 0 AND tipo = 'receita'";
    return  $this->db->query($somaCR)->row();

}
```

***Na View:***

```
<?php echo $somaReceber->SOMACR; ?>
```

[Referencia Site CodeIgniter - Generating Query Results](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

Comment: mudei na model e na view e deu esse erro: 

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: mapos/painel.php

Line Number: 104

Comment: @JardelDint peço desculpa estava no celular e fica ruim ver todas as possiblidades, eu refiz e edite, dá uma olhada agora

Comment: agora deu isso: 
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'YOUR QUERY' at line 1

YOUR QUERY

Filename: /home/molu/public_html/ossystem/models/mapos_model.php

Line Number: 119

Comment: funcionou... hehehe.. não tinha visto o YOUR QUERY... mudei pra somaCR e deu certo... MUITO OBRIGADO AMIGO!!! Me tirasse a corda do pescoço!